# Nginx rewrite rule guide

Tags: nginx

I am totally newbie on NGINX reverse proxy solution and its seems to getting hard to understand all the terminology. I am looking for a solution as follows. I would really appreciate anybody's help to configure the same.

We have an internal web server which we would like to publish at WWW site but don't want customer to see internal server URL. As example:

Customer access www.mycompany.com/track  --> NGINX read the track and then redirect URL to internal server.com.au/tracker . We dont want customer to see this address.

Any suggestion?

Cheers,

Sandy

Answer (score 2):

It is much better in this case to use the proxy. Rewrites are meant for URLs within the same domain or to redirect the client (which would show in the url).
Try this:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://internal.example.com/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting on nginx is quite the same than on Apache :) The syntax varies.
When Apache uses RewriteRule, nginx uses rewrite. May I suggest you this reference http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule ? Check 2.4 and 2.5 for rewriting-specific documentation. You'll find information about the rewrite syntax, and rewriting options.

There is a quick example from above, if you just need the basic syntax :

```
rewrite  ^(/download/.*)/media/(.*)\..*$  $1/mp3/$2.mp3  break;
```

By the way, if you want to work from examples, you can transform your Apache .htaccess file into a piece of nginx configuration, using this tool : http://winginx.com/htaccess

Comment: The OP was very specific about wanting to hide the internal URL from the user, so what's required is a proxy, not a redirect.

Comment: Which is why I did not suggest a redirect :) This my dear is rewriting, not redirecting. It will hide the actual URL if you configure it to do so.